# @Html.ActionLink() outside Area ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call an Action outside my `Admin` area, but

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }, new {Area=""})` and

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }, new {Area=""}, null)`

don't seem to work. Any idea on how to proceed with this one?

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net core ,try to set as below in startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                
            });
```

notice not reversing the order,or you will get the link like:`https://localhost:44345/Some/SomeAction?area=Admin`

The result:
[image]

If you are using asp.net MVC please show your codes in AreaRegistration.cs and RouteConfig.cs